# how would i add a transition on a div overlay

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a transition on the overlay but i can't work out which class it needs to be on to make it work. I'd like it to transition down from the top. Something along the lines of

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s;
```

HTML

```
<ul class="about-image">
<li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="overlay"><div class="bt1">Dan Morris</div><div     class="bt2">Multimedia Journalist</div></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.image{
height: 252px;
width: 252px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
background-image: url(../images/danmorris_profile.png);
}

.overlay{
width:252px;
height:252px;
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:40px;
left:0px;
}

.overlay div {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
top:40px;
margin: 40px 5px 0 0;
}

ul { list-style: none; width: 252px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 60px;

}

ul li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 252px;
height: 252px;
}

li:hover .overlay {
display:block;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.75;
}

.bt1 {
background-color:orange;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}

.bt2 {
background-color:green;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you wan the transition to fire? When you hover?

Comment: Also, could you share the HTML or a fiddle please?

Comment: yes, currently when you hover over the image an overlay appears. I would like their to be a transition on the overlay. I have added the html to the code above. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if the answer I just provided is not clear enough!

Comment: A good example is on this website sociafy.me on the agents of change section @matthewelsom

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the effect to the `.overlay` - Transition cannot be set to `transform` as it is not supported ([Reference](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/css-transitions-101/)).

To get the effect you are after, try the following:

Remove your `display: none;` - this cannot be animated.

Style your `.overlay` completely but set `top: -100%;`, `position: absolute;`, and `transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;`.

On hover, just change to `top: 0;`.

Finally, add `overflow: hidden;` to the `li` container.

```css
ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  width: 252px; 
  margin: 40px auto 60px auto;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 252px;
  height: 252px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li:hover .overlay {
  top: 0;
}
.overlay{
  width:252px;
  height:252px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:black;
  top:-100%;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay div {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  top:40px;
  margin: 40px 5px 0 0;
}
.bt1 {
  background-color:orange;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.bt2 {
  background-color:green;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="about-image">
<li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/252x252"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="bt1">Dan Morris</div>
      <div class="bt2">Multimedia Journalist</div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

For convenience I have moved your `.image` to an  element - but it will work with both. Also added some ease for smoothness.

[Pen here](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/OVRYXq)

Comment: A good example is on this website http://www.sociafy.me on the agents of change section. @matthewelsom